# Need help loading an object array with user input

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to run a small program that loads questions onto an object array based on what the user types in an input text box. This is how the HTML looks. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNdki.png

So far i've done this. i want the loop to repeat everytime the "add question" button is clicked (that button executes the function "AddQuestion"), so i added the "loop" variable, and added a for loop to show me the question's titles. but it doesn't seem to work...

```
class questions {
constructor(question, cat, ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4) {
    this.question = question;
    this.cat = cat;
    this.ans = ans1;
    this.ans2 = ans2;
    this.ans3 = ans3;
    this.ans4 = ans4;
 }
}

loop = 0

function AddQuestions()
        {
            loop++;
            var question = new Array(10);

            title = document.getElementById("question").value;
            category = document.getElementById("category").value;
            answ1 = document.getElementById("ans1").value;
            answ2 = document.getElementById("ans2").value;
            answ3 = document.getElementById("ans3").value;
            answ4 = document.getElementById("ans4").value;

            question[loop] = new questions (title, category, ans1, ans2, 
ans3, ans4);
            console.log(question[loop].question);

            for ( i = 0 < question.length; i++;) {
            console.log(question[i].question);
}

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are certain mistakes in the code. You are initiating the `loop` with `0` and within the `AddQuestions()` it is incremented immediately and your new question is added at index `1` instead of `0`. Instead increment the loop variable after the question is added.

The statement `for ( i = 0 < question.length; i++;) {` is incorrect. It should be `for ( i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {`

In `AddQuestions()`, an array of `question`(Since `question` is an array, rename variable `question` to `questions`) is created with fixed `length` of 10 elements. so the for loop `for ( i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {` will iterate over the `empty` elements too. Instead, you can create an array using - `var question = []`;

Also every time the `question` is set to empty array when the `button` is clicked, which will erase already inserted items earlier. Instead declare the array once outside the function `AddQuestions`.

```js
class questions {
  constructor(question, cat, ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4) {
    this.question = question;
    this.cat = cat;
    this.ans = ans1;
    this.ans2 = ans2;
    this.ans3 = ans3;
    this.ans4 = ans4;
  }
}

let loop = 0;
const question = [];

function AddQuestions() {
  title = document.getElementById("question").value;
  category = document.getElementById("category").value;
  answ1 = document.getElementById("ans1").value;
  answ2 = document.getElementById("ans2").value;
  answ3 = document.getElementById("ans3").value;
  answ4 = document.getElementById("ans4").value;

  question[loop] = new questions(title, category, answ1, answ2, answ3, answ4);

  for (i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {
    console.log(question[i].question);
  }
  loop++;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="question">
<input type="text" id="category">
<input type="text" id="ans1">
<input type="text" id="ans2">
<input type="text" id="ans3">
<input type="text" id="ans4">
<button onclick="AddQuestions()">Click</button>
```

Comment: this makes perfect sense, but i tried to run it and when i enter the first question it works fine, however when i enter the second question the console says; Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined
    at AddQuestions (code.js:31)
line 31 is  console.log(question[i].question); . i'm very confused.

Comment: @azusdhfjdg - The problem is within `AddQuestions()` you set `question` array to empty i:e `question = [];`. which will make the array empty everytime you click Add button. Instead declare the array outside of function `AddQuestions`. I have updated code snippet.

Comment: @azusdhfjdg - If the answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted to indicate that problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is starting from 0, but the question array index starts from 1. You need to move the `loop++;` command to the end of the `AddQuestions` function

Comment: My code still doesn't work :/ when i enter the first question it works fine, but when i enter the second question i get a console error that says; Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined at AddQuestions (code.js:31) line 31 is console.log(question[i].question);. i'm very confused as to why it doesn't work

Comment: Well you need to declare the question array outside the AddQuestions function. Try to move this line `var question = new Array(10);` outside AddQuestions function and below the line `loop = 0`